# LINQ to MongoDB: .Any with a Predicate

Tags: linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Collection in `MongoDB` of S documents.  Each `S` has a collection of `UserPermission objects`, each of which have a `UserId` property.  I want to select all the `S` documents that have a `UserPermission` with a certain `UserId`:

```
return collection.Where(s => s.UserPermissions.Any(up => up.UserId == userIdString)).ToList();
```

I get an error telling me that `.Any` with a predicate is not supported.  The MongoDB docs say: "You can usually rewrite such a query by putting an equivalent where clause before the projection (in which case you can drop the projection)."

What does that mean? Any idea how I would change my query to get around this limitation?

Here's a full example. You can see I've tried 2 different queries and neither is supported:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

namespace MongoSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            App app1 = new App() { Name = "App1", Users = new List<User>() 
                { 
                    new User() { UserName = "Chris" } } 
                };

            App app2 = new App() { Name = "App2", Users = new List<User>() 
                { 
                    new User() { UserName = "Chris" }, 
                    new User() { UserName = "Carlos" } } 
                };

            MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create();
            MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("test");
            MongoCollection appCollection = database.GetCollection("app");

            appCollection.Insert(app1);
            appCollection.Insert(app2);

            // Throws "Any with a predicate not supported" error
            //var query = appCollection.AsQueryable<App>()
            //    .Where(a => a.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Carlos"));

            // Throws "Unsupported Where Clause" error.
            var query = appCollection.AsQueryable<App>()
                .Where(a => a.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "Carlos").Any());

            foreach (App loadedApp in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(loadedApp.ToJson());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class App
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the builder, I can accomplish the above with this: var builder = appCollection.FindAs<App>(Query.EQ("Users.UserName", "Carlos"));

Comment: You should use the Query builder to do this. This way you can be sure that not all your documents are loaded before the linq expression is executed. The Query is send all the way down to MongoDB and used on the cursor. If you have many documents in your collection, then you should also do a ToList() to turn the cursor into a list, because the cursor can consume alot of memory.

Answer (score 3):

`Any()` without a predicate is supported, so you can do:

```
collection.Where(s => s.UserPermissions
    .Where(up => up.UserId == userIdString).Any() )
```

(this is the "equivalent where clause" put before the `Any`)

Comment: This returns an "unsupported where clause error."  I've added a full sample in the original question.

Comment: Oh dear. It looks like you have to use two queries: one to fetch UserId's from UserPermissions, followed by a `ContainsAny`.

Comment: Any is not currently supported, or nested where clauses.  However, Any has been coded and tested in master and will be in the next release.

Comment: As Craig promised, I updated to yesterday to 1.5 and it looks like this issue is fixed.

Comment: Does anyone know where the description of what IS supported in the MongDB Linq implementation is?